# How to send a video file with GNURadio and USRP's?

Tags: video, h.264, gstreamer, gnuradio, usrp

I am trying to send a video file using GNURadio,GRC and USRP1's with a RFX2400 and a 2.4GHZ antenna using a .ts video file. We have two USRP's, one working as the transmitter and the other as the receiver. We are using GMSK modulation and demodulation with the encoding and decoding done before and after the modulation and demod is done, as well as the constant multiplying before sending the signal from one USRP to the other. Low pass filtering is done to the received signal before demodulating it and decoding it, this is then saved to a video_output.ts file.

Here is where we have our current problem. We have a video that we made ourselves. When we send this video across our output video file never contains information even though we can see because of an FFT sink placed in between the LPF and the USRP source that something is being received on the USRP. How can I make it so that I actually save those bytes that are coming in.

We read that we are going to have to create two piping files using mkfifo command and then copying the video file we want to transmit to the piping file created and then we should be able to send a file properly. This is then giving me some extra problems. Ive been installing packages that would include x264 and h264 encoding in any way but still gives the error that no type of encoding found. We did make install to the x264 package and still wouldnt work. So atm we are stuck in trying to encode our video file to the piping  file created.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you send and recover any sort of digital data successfully yet?  Is your filter appropriate to your occupied bandwidth?

Comment: Havent been able to. We've been having problems as well that we think are due to having the USRP2 and not having the necessary blocks needed for the USRP2 (ex. the USRP2 source). In terms of the filter it was extracted from an already existing example.They were transmitting a 1.23 GHz, all we did was up it to 2.45 in order to send it using our available equipment. And in any case, the LPF cutoff frequency we arent able to increase it above sample_rate/2, some limiting factor in the specs of the LPF, dont really understand that.

Comment: And more in terms of the recovery, we just have an empty file in the output after we have both teh receiver and transmitter running for some time. We've tried closing the receiver after the video was sent and opening the file while the receiver is on.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you need to back, way, way up, and see if you can find some theoretical texts and simple demos for your system before you try to do fancy things with it.  Then you won't be surprised by basic concepts such as how the nyquist theorem effectively limits the LPF to below half the sampling frequency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will suggest you to start with more easy applications and when you sure that this step is ok, proceed to the next.

For example at the beginning forget the USRPs. Use the File source blocks and try to send a file containing in each line an increasing counter or whatever you want doesn't matter. Pass it through your modulation scheme and at the same flow graph demodulate and save it with a file sink block. Now check if the two files are the same.

If yes do the same examle, but now using the usrps and transmitting over the air. If also this succeeds, you can then start playing with video transmission.

Note that you should play also at the simulation phase, by adding some noise to see how your systems reacts because possibly your environment at the 2.4GHZ may be noisy.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Chris, you have to learn to walk before you sign up for a Marathon.

If I was you, I would start by going over some of the examples that exist inside the GR tree under GNUradio-examples directory.

It also helps if you watch a few videos that people put on Youtube showing how they did similar work such as this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtlyNlRAHGM
And these:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZe3r4EK_7E
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VUZ7H60F68

You maybe able to find a lot of help of you check this site:
http://www.wu.ece.ufl.edu/projects/wirelessVideo/project/H264_USRP/index.htm

And contact the team who did the job, they maybe able to help you with your problem.

Best regards,
Farhad Abdolian